# Google shows my store/website on the right but not on search results, is this ok?

Tags: seo, google-search, knowledge-graph

I have this local shop on Google Places/Maps and there's a website and everything. When people search for the name of the shop/site, it shows on the right-hand side of Google Search results with address, pictures, map location, open hours, website link, directions, etc... But it does not appear on search results.

Is this how it works? Is this expected? Or should it appear on search results too (assuming proper SEO is in place)?

Comment: Can you get your site name on Google, if you type `site:yourdomain.com`. And what kind of results you're getting on main page?. Such a thing only happen when same query have different meanings and so Google have to show different results as well. So analysis other pages as well, and add some more info in your question..

Comment: @Goyllo Yes, I get the main page in the results when I search with `site:domain.com`. There are no other results because for now it's just a single page with a logo and a few contact options. The other results include our Facebook page, our old blog page and similar titled results (we have `Peace` in the title and google shows a lot of results for `Piece`). What kind of additional information are you looking for?

Comment: Google show instead words when the query is not recognized very well. It's purely based on number of query and number of clicks you get in your website. If site:domain.com display your site, it means Google have index your content fine, you just did not have [good ranking for your keywords](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google). So yes that's how it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this how it works? Is this expected?

Yes and yes. Congratulations, Google has recognised your business listing.

> Or should it appear on search results too

It arguably already does appear in the search results. Displaying all that information in amongst the actual search results (on the left) would be cumbersome.

Or I assume you mean that you are expecting to see at least a link to your website in the SERPs? Yes, you would indeed expect this. However, since your site is "just a single page with a logo and a few contact options", I expect Google does not yet think this is index worthy. Add some meaningful content etc. and you can expect to see your site in the SERPs in time.

Comment: "I expect Google does not yet think this is index worthy." - Is that how it works?

Comment: Google tries to deliver a good user experience. It wouldn't be very good to return a page in the SERPs that didn't actually contain anything. Either that, or Google has not yet indexed that page? How long has the page been live? Have you created a property in GSC?

Comment: It doesn't contain much but I wouldn't say it doesn't contain anything, there's important contact information along with links for important social networks and a maps location for directions. It's been alive for a few months, it's displayed as a search result for `site:example.com` so it's indexed and yes I've added properties in GSC.

Comment: All this information is correctly displayed on the right side as business listing (with a `Website` link), I know. But it would be nice if one of the first results was the site itself too. I've just tested for other business and it showed both results.

Comment: Just noticed that Google actually shows the result I was looking for, in the 11th position. I guess I have lots of SEO work to do. Just not sure what else can I do given that we don't have much content for now.